# How to add entries to a dataframe based on calculations using the previous entry in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe `growth_rates` that looks like this:

```
Year        SSP2 Growth Rate        National Total
2018             0.00234                139538
2019             0.00234                139538
2020             0.00234                NA
2021             0.00090                NA
2022             0.00090                NA
...
2100            -0.01023                NA
```

There is an `SSP2 Growth Rate` for every `Year`, but `National Total` after 2019 = NA. I need to fill in the NA's using the following calculation: National Total = (National Total of the year prior) * (1 + SSP2 Growth Rate of that year). So, for example, 2020 National Total = 139538 * (1 + 0.00234).

Can only use dplyr, tidyr, or base R to do this.

Thanks!

Data:

```
> dput(growth_rates)
structure(list(Year = 2010:2100, `SSP2 Growth Rate` = c(0.0033, 
0.0033, 0.0033, 0.0033, 0.0033, 0.0033, 0.00234, 0.00234, 0.00234, 
0.00234, 0.00234, 9e-04, 9e-04, 9e-04, 9e-04, 9e-04, -6e-04, 
-6e-04, -6e-04, -6e-04, -6e-04, -0.00218, -0.00218, -0.00218, 
-0.00218, -0.00218, -0.00372, -0.00372, -0.00372, -0.00372, -0.00372, 
-0.00512, -0.00512, -0.00512, -0.00512, -0.00512, -0.00643, -0.00643, 
-0.00643, -0.00643, -0.00643, -0.00758, -0.00758, -0.00758, -0.00758, 
-0.00758, -0.00854, -0.00854, -0.00854, -0.00854, -0.00854, -0.00924, 
-0.00924, -0.00924, -0.00924, -0.00924, -0.00969, -0.00969, -0.00969, 
-0.00969, -0.00969, -0.01012, -0.01012, -0.01012, -0.01012, -0.01012, 
-0.01058, -0.01058, -0.01058, -0.01058, -0.01058, -0.01091, -0.01091, 
-0.01091, -0.01091, -0.01091, -0.0109, -0.0109, -0.0109, -0.0109, 
-0.0109, -0.01061, -0.01061, -0.01061, -0.01061, -0.01061, -0.01023, 
-0.01023, -0.01023, -0.01023, -0.01023), `National Total` = c(134091L, 
134735L, 135404L, 136072L, 136782L, 137462L, 138271L, 139008L, 
139538L, 140005L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -91L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @akrun sorry about that, better now?

Comment: The final compute for last year is extremely big!

Comment: @Duck Really? 2100 should = 785379.6367

Comment: It is similar to your number but extremely big. Could you check the calculation? I think in each iteration you use the new computed previous value.

Comment: @Duck Yes that is correct, for 2100 we use the 2099 computed value

Comment: Check the solution the final number is to power 93, is that right?

Comment: Why is it multiplying by 10? I can get 78537.9 as the final value using `cumprod(1 + tail(growth_rates[["SSP2 Growth Rate"]], -10)) * growth_rates[["National Total"]][10]` which is just a compounding growth which seems to fit with the series.

Comment: Ah yes- my mistake, all years prior to 2020 are multiplied by 10 due to a unit conversion. The * 10 should be removed, updating the post now.

Comment: Is the formula changed?

Comment: @akrun Formula is changed. National Total = National Total of the year prior * (1 + SSP2 Growth Rate of that year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is cumulative/compound growth, which means the ol' `cum`ulative `prod`uct can be used to do all the calculations in a vectorised fashion, taking the last known value as the starting point:

```
growth_rates[["National Total"]][-(1:10)] <- {
  cumprod(1 + tail(growth_rates[["SSP2 Growth Rate"]], -10)) *
    growth_rates[["National Total"]][10]
}
```

Seems to return a likely looking result:

```
plot(`National Total` ~ `Year`, data=growth_rates, type="l")
```

[image]

Comment: This is probably the fastest solution. +1

Comment: When I use this solution, I still have NA's for all years > 2019?

Comment: @MarideeWeber - just checked with a fresh run of your `dput` data and this code and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This works using the new modification:

```
#Detect index
index <- min(which(is.na(growth_rates$`National Total`)))
# val <- growth_rates$`National Total`[index-1]
#Loop
for(i in index:dim(growth_rates)[1])
{
  growth_rates$`National Total`[i] <- (growth_rates$`National Total`[i-1])*(1+growth_rates$`SSP2 Growth Rate`[i])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `accumulate` from `purrr`.  It works and it is simple and it should work for multiple cases without much constraints

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
out <- growth_rates %>% 
    mutate(`National Total` = accumulate2(`National Total`,
        `SSP2 Growth Rate`[-1], 
        ~ if(!is.na(..1) & is.na(..2)) (..3 + 1) * (..1) else ..2) %>% 
       flatten_dbl)

tail(out, 5)
#   Year SSP2 Growth Rate National Total
#87 2096         -0.01023       81835.64
#88 2097         -0.01023       80998.46
#89 2098         -0.01023       80169.85
#90 2099         -0.01023       79349.71
#91 2100         -0.01023       78537.96
```

---

Or with `Reduce` from `base R`

```
growth_rates$`National Total`[-c(1:10)] <- Reduce(function(x, y) 
  (y  + 1) * x, growth_rates$`SSP2 Growth Rate`[-c(1:10)], 
   init = growth_rates$`National Total`[10], accumulate = TRUE)[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

With the humble `for` loop -

```
for(i in 11:nrow(growth_rates)) {
  growth_rates[i, "National Total"] <- 
    with(growth_rates, `National Total`[i-1] * (1 + `SSP2 Growth Rate`[i]))
}

tail(growth_rates)

   Year SSP2 Growth Rate National Total
86 2095         -0.01061       82681.47
87 2096         -0.01023       81835.64
88 2097         -0.01023       80998.46
89 2098         -0.01023       80169.85
90 2099         -0.01023       79349.71
91 2100         -0.01023       78537.96
```